# Linear Regression - Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am trying to make a model that can predict the wine quality based on the wine data.
I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Feature alcohool is not in features dictionary.

But I ran `print(feature_columns)` and that was the output:

```
[NumericColumn(key='fixed acidity', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='volatile acidity', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='citric acid', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='residual sugar', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='chlorides', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='free sulfur dioxide', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='total sulfur dioxide', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='density', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='pH', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='sulphates', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='alcohool', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None), NumericColumn(key='quality', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float64, normalizer_fn=None)]
```

**`alcohool` is there** I can't understand what's going on. The error occurs at: `linear_est.train(train_input_fn)` when I am trying to train my model.

My model looks like this:

```
dftrain = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv').head(790)
dfeval = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv').tail(809)
y_train = dftrain.pop('quality')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('quality')


CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = []
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['fixed acidity','volatile acidity','citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide','density','pH','sulphates','alcohool','quality']
feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique() #gets a lsit of all unique values from given feature column
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))
  
for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype = tf.float64))
```

Input function:

```
# INPUT FUNCTION
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():  # inner function, this will be returned
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))  # create tf.data.Dataset object with data and its label
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)  # randomize order of data
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)  # split dataset into batches of 32 and repeat process for number of epochs
    return ds  # return a batch of the dataset
  return input_function  # return a function object for use

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)  # here we will call the input_function that was returned to us to get a dataset object we can feed to the model
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)


linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
# We create a linear estimtor by passing the feature columns we created earlier


linear_est.train(train_input_fn)  # train
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)  # get model metrics/stats by testing on tetsing data

clear_output()  # clears consoke output
print(result['accuracy'])  # the result variable is simply a dict of stats about our model
```

Comment: You have `alcohool` in `feature_columns` - the list of features you expect. Have you verified that all samples in the input data contain this feature? Perhaps iterate over the whole dataset and check for existence of this column.

Comment: alcohool does exist in mt dataframe

Comment: I suggest you try what I said anyway :)

Comment: Should I do  a for loop in my dftrain, dfeval, y_train and y_eval?

Comment: Yes, I think something like this.